# Create Array or direct from database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Okey, so I have this javascript app and need some input/tips.

This is what a want to do, and I will go over what I have in mind of solving this:

With this app, users will log in and try to destroy a 'boss' and every user works together in this play. So lets say this 'boss' have 10 million in health and each player takes 1 health per hit or more with boost ( <- but this is not part of the question). 
So what I do now is that I store each player hits in a database and through ajax I get the total hits all the time so the players will always know how much life this 'boss' have left.

Here comes the real question, how should I set the 'boss' health and image? Because when the 'boss' have been defeated I would like a new boss appear maybe in 24 hours or so(but thats also not apart of this question) and after like 10 different 'bosses' the hole process repeats itself.

This is how Im dealing with this problem right now, I have setup a table in my database with ID, bossHealth, BossImg and BossComplete. So lets if 'boss' number one have been defeated, it will update the database with BossComplete = 1 and if not defeated = 0.

Everything works as it should, but this would take longer time to load and not that mobile if the user has slow internet connection. What I had in mind that maybe setup an array straight in the code, with the same data (health, imgsrc, and so on), and when the 'boss' is defeated it will go to the next 'boss'.

Im looking for other examples on how to solve this or just pointers. Thanks in advance and hope some of you know maybe a better way or more efficient way.

Comment: Looks more like an organized denial of service attack than an Internet game to me. I reckon your pool of DB connections will run dry before the boss of the day even broke a sweat.

Comment: Well, the 'boss' isn't gone before it has been taking all of the health. And what do you mean by 'organized denial of service'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Ajax would be very good here. I would recommend WebSockets. You can check demos here: http://www.websocket.org/demos.html. For example this seems very nice http://rumpetroll.com/.

Try to keep it lightweight on server or you will run out of juice as kuroi neko mentioned. For example if every player would be polling requests to server and interfering with database, your service would go down very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will check it out :)

Comment: after a long search and researching about websockets, I found out that theres no possible method to run websockets on my domain. As my provider dosn't support websockets. Is there something else you can suggest to make the request go faster and easier?